# Why HttpWebRequest timeout on 3rd or more call?

Tags: c#, timeout, httpwebrequest, httpwebresponse

I need check an url exist or not, then my code :

```
   private bool CheckConnection(String URL)
    {
        try
        {
            HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(URL);
            request.UseDefaultCredentials = true;
            request.KeepAlive = false;
            request.Timeout = 5000;
            request.ReadWriteTimeout = 5000;
            request.ServicePoint.ConnectionLeaseTimeout = 5000;
            request.ServicePoint.MaxIdleTime = 5000;
            bool bReturn = false;
            using (var response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse())
            {
                bReturn = (response.StatusCode == HttpStatusCode.OK);
            }
            request.Abort();

        return bReturn;
        }
        catch
        {
            return false;
        }
    }
```

I receive message "timeout" on 3rd call, I search and fix but can not success.
Can anyone help me?

Thanks all

Answer (score 3):

I was struggling with the same problem and after some R&D i troubleshooted by closing the `HttpResponse` object after asserting the response code in loop: `response.Close();`

**My Code:**

```
HttpWebRequest webRequest = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(url);
HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)webRequest.GetResponse();
int respcode = (int)response.StatusCode;
Assert.IsTrue(respcode == 302 || respcode == 200);
response.Close();
```

Answer (score 0):

Try below code.Once i had same issue and i fixed it using this example. Hope this work for you too.

```
  using (var client = new WebClient())
        {
          var values = new NameValueCollection
         {
            { "key", "This is a test that posts this string to a Web server." }
         };
            string url = "http://www.contoso.com/PostAccepter.aspx";
            byte[] result = client.UploadValues(url, values);
            Console.WriteLine(Encoding.UTF8.GetString(result));
        }
```

Comment: as you suggest, but at 3rd call, it will delay after webclient timeout (100s) then process this function :(